# Headers, Content-Types defaults for browsers, CLI, apps

Tags: php, http, content-type

Each browser has defined "own" by default if not sent by headers own Content-Type. For example, Firefox returns `text/html; charset=utf-8`.

If I check on Firefox on blank page and reload some PHP file it will return `text/html; charset=utf-8` content-type.

This is defined from Firefox? Or APACHE server?

I'm confusing with DEFAULT `Content-Type' or where I can find lists of all default content type headers if not defined by client or sending HTTP header Content-Type.

For example, on which application is used to request header with RFC 822 like `text/plain; charset=us-ascii`.

---

1. What I can do is first get available headers (ex: `text/plain;text/html`) from browsers and then set in Content-Type for `text/plain` if is exists.
2. If not headers sent I want to know which content-type should be by default browser/cli. Possible all default lists of Content-Type for all user agents?

---

Real question: How to get `Content-Type` by default from browser using PHP but not receiving `NULL`. On browser if you `refresh` you will see `Content-Type` header but on PHP you will not receive.

Comment: It's very hard to understand your question. I read this 10 times and gave up: `Each browser has defined "own" by default if not sent by headers own Content-Type.`

Comment: Open firefox. Go to `about:config` and find `network.http.accept.default`. You can see default http accept header. I need lists of other browsers. If you trying get `Content-Type` using `$_SERVER` you will got from firefox default http `network.http.accept.default` value. If you set using header it will change. I want to get from $_SERVER but this is not possible.

Comment: By default PHP HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE is null. If you set by header sent it will change and returns value. But I want to know BEFORE and on situation when is NULL.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1477685/4621324

Comment: Some details, how Chromium does it: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/net/base/mime_sniffer.cc&sq=package:chromium&type=cs

Comment: I think is correct answer that different browser set default Content-Type. For example, elinks and curl by default returns `*/*`.  Neither of that is not defined in documentation. For another browser and mostly you can see `text/html`. What I want is to fetch this value and return using PHP  that value not `NULL` and not using headers like PHP function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is in that way:

1. Check if HTTP_ACCEPT exists from browser, if it exists for example:

   ```
   text/html
   ```

   Make return Content-Type: `text/html`

   If not exists check

   ```
   */*
   ```

   Make returns Content-Type:

   ```
    text/plain; us-ascii
   ```

   > This is by RFC 822:
   >   http://mattryall.net/blog/2008/03/default-content-type

   Then, if is not defined then use `text/plain`.
2. If not HTTP_ACCEPT exists than use RFC 822 declaration as:

   ```
   text/plain; us-ascii
   ```

   > This is accept for CLI and should be ASCII defined by RFC 822.
3. Older browser such as SAFARI checks extension in a URL such as `.htm` then should be `text/html` in other way returns `text/plain`. Newer browser by default is `text/html`.
4. Firefox 2 returns `application/*` if is not defined so in some situation you can check using `USER_AGENT` and then set by default declarition. This is old browser and you should avoid this.
5. I wrote this script and works fine. Header should be sent if it is forced by script and if is needle.

*If you have some suggestions or if I'm mistake some on it please correct me.*